# Multiple Global.asax files per web application project

Tags: asp.net, wcf, appdomain, global-asax

I have existing web application project in which i need to add new subdirectory. In this subdirectory i need to add WCF service.

Question is: Can i use different AppDomain then services from root directory? Also, can i add new global.asax just for this subdirectory?

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing in your question that wont stop you from defining the subdirectory as a new web application within IIS, thus allowing you to create new global.asax/web.config. Just remember that the web.config configuration is inherited by default, and you'll need to remove any handlers that your parent site added, but your subsite does not have.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the situation that the global.asax file has to be different then you are almost always better off splitting the service out to it's own project and deployment location.

This way changes in the main site won't impact the web service.